# How to implement a "click-anywhere-to-continue" event on my android activity?

Tags: android

Is this possible?

I would display an activity that shows a welcome page, and that welcome page doesn't have any Views where I can attach an `onClickListener`.

EDIT: ok, the reason for this welcome kind of welcome page, is that this application is used to take something like a survey... after a customer is done with the survey, the app returns to this welcome page so another person can take the survey again.

Comment: are you using any xml layout for welcome page?

Comment: yes, its a relative layout, with background set to the welcome page as a big image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the original layout is somehow not appropriate, use a FrameLayout at the top level of your layout to achieve this. FrameLayout allows stackable views/layouts, so you can have your existing view as the bottom layer, and then a transparent view on top that listens for the touch event:

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- Put your complete original layout/view here -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_to_listen_for_touch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the hat tip.. i followed this approach and now i'm thinking i couldn't have been more stupid not to have thought about this in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

try like this,

welcome screen xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

add this in your activity,

```
private RelativeLayout mainLayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);

        mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

               mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                      // here you can write code to proceed next step.
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an XML layout for this page. And using at least one ViewGroup (e.g Linear Layout/Relative Layout etc). Put an id to this ViewGroup element and In the Activity initialize this ViewGroup element using find view by id. Now set the click listener to the ViewGroup element